# Setting width with percent value

Tags: android, android-xml

I am trying to create an activity with few text boxes arranged in two columns. I the two columns have width 30% of the screen and the other with remaining 70% of the screen. Here is my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="naming is fun fun is naming" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hi" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg_right" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hi" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg_right" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hi" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The problem is the column with text "hi" is taking 30% of the screen but a word like "hello" takes more space and the formation is distorted.

Whatever the size of the text may be it should take at max 30% of the screen. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use layout_gravity then set the corresponding height/widht to 0. Also I found not reason to use extra Nested Linear Layouts. Perhaps you can use something like this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:text="Hi" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:text="Hi" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:text="Hi" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:text="Hi" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have few extra elements too so I have the extra `LinearLayout` which was not relevant to my question hence I removed..

Answer (score 0):

The layout_width of the linear layouts containing textviews should be 0 dp.

Use -

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

instead of using -

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Because when you are defining the weights you dont have to define the width. Weigths will automatically take care of the width.

See if this helps.

**EDIT -** 
this xml should work fine -

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="naming is fun fun is naming" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hi" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hi" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hi" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which width should I change? Could you post an update based on my code?

Answer (score 0):

1. you should consider table view for the proper formations you can specify the layout_wieght   there too.
2. set the width of the textviews to fill_parent if you are using layout_wieght because it's the allocated space for it.
3. Use the single line enabled for the textview, if required you can marquee the text.

Edit

It's not working because of this

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" //wrap_content
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg_right" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"//wrap_content
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hi" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

you are not assiging the alloted space to the textview

Comment: My text won't be more that 5-7 characters. I have considered table layout too but, I wanted to know why this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for TextView. If this does'nt solves it try increasing or decreasing the value instead of 3 according to your situation

```
android:ems = "3"
```